# Material Design on top of Zurb Foundation

Tags: css, zurb-foundation, material-design

My web app is built using Zurb Foundation for the UI layer. The more I read about Material Design (getmdl.io) the more I like it. I also understand that the Material Design toolkit is not comprehensive as Foundation or Bootstrap maybe. So my question is - is it possible for me to use both? For example - use Foundation for layout etc and use Material Design for stylesheet and components?

Or am I completely missing the point and would be creating an application that would be a nightmare to maintain? Advice welcome..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer to your question is yes you could use both but the work required to get them both playing nice together would be a huge undertaking.

Personally, I think using both is more trouble then it's worth as they essentially are the same thing (Front-end frameworks) however, one admittedly is more aesthetically appealing. Since you're already using Foundation I would stick with it.

You can always take specific components from Material Design that you like and include them with Foundation although this would be much easier if you were using the scss version.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe the project referred below will help, if that's the direction that you want go.

**Material Design version of Foundation Framework by Zurb**

http://eucalyptuss.github.io/material-foundation/

Comment: Link currently 404's so this Github was either made private or deleted